# Electron js - Spawn child process is working on one windows machine but not on the other

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

```
const child = spawn(
  'cmd.exe',
  [
    '/K',
    path.join(getBinariesDirectoryPath(), 'GenericEXE_livestream.exe'),
    '--ip_address',
    `${cameraData.camera.ip}`,
    '--username',
    `${cameraData.camera.user}`,
    '--password',
    `${cameraData.camera.password}`,
    '--channel_no',
    `${cameraData.camera.channel}`,
    '--rtsp_port_no',
    `${cameraData.camera.rtsp}`,
    '--cctv_id',
    `${cameraData.camera.currentBranch[1]}`,
    // '--jwt_token',
    // `${token}`,
    '--branch_id',
    `${cameraData.camera.currentBranch[0][0].id}`,
    '--dashboard_url',
    `${URL}`,
    '--fps',
    `${cameraData.camera.fps}`,
    '--branch_name',
    `${cameraData.camera.currentBranch[0][0].branch_name}`,
  ],
  options
);
child.on('error', function(err) {
  alert(err);
});
child.unref();`
```

I am trying to run a python executable from the electron app using spawn. In development mode, it works. When making an exe package for production, on one windows machine it works but not on another machine. The previous version of the same electron app was working on the other machine but after adding 2-3 args it stopped working on the other machine. Been bugging me the whole day.

Comment: Does this bug have anything to do with the argument length?

Comment: I Will try on a 3rd machine tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: whats `alert(err);` show?

Comment: Check the output on stdout and stderror.

Comment: alert shows nothing

Comment: haven't checked stdout. Let me check it.

Comment: Send a file stream to stdio for stdout and stderror.  Have it write to a temp file somewhere.  This way it still works in a production build and you can test it on other machines quickly and see the output.

Comment: @Trevor found the issue. cmd is throwing an error because there is a space path of executable (aka user name of the system)